# Python, Class errors while appending to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to append to a list by using a Class, however I get the following error:
`TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`

This is the code:

```
lijst = []

# Class voor Student
class Student:
# Constructor
def __init__(self):
    self.__achternaam = ''
    self.__voornaam = ''

# Attribuut achternaam
def setAchternaam(self, achternaam):
    self.__achternaam = achternaam

def getAchternaam(self):
    return self.__achternaam
achternaam = property(getAchternaam, setAchternaam)

# Attribuut voornaam
def setVoornaam(self, voornaam):
    self.__voornaam = voornaam

def getVoornaam(self):
    return self.__voornaam
voornaam = property(getVoornaam, setVoornaam)

lijst.append(Student('Quinten' , 'Vollmer'))
lijst.append(Student('Jochem' , 'Legue'))
lijst.append(Student('Johan' , 'Jansen'))
```

I have tried the following:

```
class Student:
# Constructor
def __init__(self, achternaam, voornaam):
    self.__achternaam = achternaam
    self.__voornaam = voornaam
```

However the output becomes:

```
[<__main__.Student object at 0x0000017614279FD0>, <__main__.Student object at 0x00000176142798E0>, <__main__.Student object at 0x00000176142797F0>]
```

Don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You solved the first problem, but the second behaviour is expected. If you want the output to look different, you'll have to write a function/method for it, which could be `__repr__` or `__str__` if you want that function to be called implicitly when printing.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: I want to add the first names (voornaam) and last names(achternaam) to the list.
So the list should contain:
Quinten Vollmer, Jochem Legue, Johan Jansen

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this

```
    class Student:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, achternaam, voornaam):
       self.__achternaam = achternaam
       self.__voornaam = voornaam
```

is correct. You're probably just getting a weird looking output because your data type can't be printed as easily as a string or something else that Python knows how to print, so it's just telling you where the object is stored in memory.

Comment: Okay thanks, how do I change it to get the correct output?

Comment: You would need to write a __str__ method, like this:

def __str__(self) -line break-
   return ("the value of voornam is:  " + self.voornam)